# SQLite order by cast decimal and 'unknown' value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to order my values in my SQLite database by a value they have stored in state ( this is a varchar 255)

the field can contain anything, but for the `entity_id` that I select it will contain a decimal number or `'unknown'`

so I tried the following query but it won't work:

```
select 
    state, 
    attributes, 
    created 
from states 
where state <> 'unknown' 
    and (entity_id = 'sensor.speedtest_download' or entity_id = 'sensor.fastcom_download') 
order by cast(state as DECIMAL) DESC
Limit 0,30
```

if I leave the `order by` out of the query I get results like:

```
"61.8"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Fast.com Download""}"   "2016-12-11 19:00:30.842672"
"65.45" "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-11 21:30:18.669531"
"65.45" "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-11 21:41:30.850441"
"73.5"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Fast.com Download""}"   "2016-12-11 22:00:30.919995"
"70.14" "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-11 22:00:31.098129"
"91.7"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Fast.com Download""}"   "2016-12-11 23:00:30.787601"
"80.72" "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-11 23:00:30.951527"
"76.5"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Fast.com Download""}"   "2016-12-12 00:00:30.844100"
"74.87" "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-12 00:00:31.013408"
"91.7"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Fast.com Download""}"   "2016-12-12 01:00:30.838618"
"83.5"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-12 01:00:30.976214"
"92.2"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Fast.com Download""}"   "2016-12-12 02:00:30.743759"
"83.71" "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-12 02:00:30.899923"
"84.4"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Fast.com Download""}"   "2016-12-12 03:00:30.814488"
"73.27" "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-12 03:00:30.941021"
"78.9"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Fast.com Download""}"   "2016-12-12 04:00:30.751924"
"77.79" "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-12 04:00:30.926943"
"90.6"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Fast.com Download""}"   "2016-12-12 05:00:30.762564"
"82.41" "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-12 05:00:31.452064"
"71.3"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Fast.com Download""}"   "2016-12-12 06:00:30.875047"
"64.83" "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-12 06:00:31.015236"
"90.9"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Fast.com Download""}"   "2016-12-12 07:00:30.770224"
"78.18" "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-12 07:00:30.925578"
"86.2"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Fast.com Download""}"   "2016-12-12 08:00:30.837426"
"61.4"  "{""unit_of_measurement"": ""Mbit/s"", ""friendly_name"": ""Download""}"    "2016-12-12 08:00:30.990303"
```

with the `order by` i get:

```
database disk image is malformed: select state,  created from states 
where state <> 'unknown' and (entity_id = 'sensor.speedtest_download' or entity_id = 'sensor.fastcom_download') 
order by cast(state as DECIMAL) DESC
Limit 0,30
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample data for state, created and entity_id, also post your desired output. You can minimize your query output data though it's helpful.

Comment: @Suraz my desired result is the one I show, but the first value from high to low, and the sample data  = same as the one shown, but with some lines where in the first value is 'unknown'